# How to parse json in lua?

Tags: json, nginx, lua

Is there any lightweight, preferably pure lua, library for lua to parse json content? Basically I wanna augment my ngnix with a lua module that needs to verfiy some information from a `json` object I'm getting from `Redis`.

The object looks like as follow:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "username": "username",
      "type": "TYPE"
    }
  },
  "passport": {
    "user": "uuid"
  },
}
```

In my lua code, I need to verify if the `data.user.username` exists. Then I can let the nginx continue with its redirection. Can anybody please show me an example of how can I achieve that?

Comment: The easy answer just pick library you like. There many of them :)

Comment: [1](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules), [2](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON data in that form is very close to Lua tables. So you can transform the JSON data into Lua code and run it, if you trust the JSON data.

```
J=[[
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "username": "username",
      "type": "TYPE"
    }
  },
  "passport": {
    "user": "uuid"
  },
}
]]
L="return "..J:gsub('("[^"]-"):','[%1]=')
T=loadstring(L)()
print(T.data.user.username)
```

If have any qualms about the JSON data, you may want to run the string in `L` in a sandbox.

Comment: Why would you use loadstring?

Comment: @warspyking Because among the "pure lua" ways, this is almost certainly the fastest. And it can be done [in a safe way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41945465/805875). (Unless there's a really ugly bug in the Lua parser, but that's quite unlikely.) Further, there's a difference in threat level between e.g. a web API exposed to unknown (and quite likely some malicious) data and a tool that you use to quickly load data generated out of some other trusted tool running locally (even if _that_ tool interfaces with the 'net).

Comment: I understand what it does, but loadstring for something so simple is really expensive don't you think?

Comment: @warspyking, I doubt that hand-written JOSN parsers in pure Lua will be faster or use less memory than the Lua parser, but I haven't measured anything.

Comment: This is works only for limited subset of JSON. And even in this example JSON is not valid but it parse without any error.

Comment: ^ Yeah, and there should be care for the JSON source encoding

Comment: loadstring is not a native json thing.