# How to turn ":" into "=" when printing a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, lua

So I am using Python to get a JSON request, and making a dictionary out of it. Now I need to convert it to Lua so I can paste the dictionary into my Lua code; I am having trouble turning `:` into `=` since there are a lot of dictionaries.

For example, the Python dictionary when printed is
`{"key" : value}`
while the Lua table only accepts `{"key" = value}`.

Comment: Doesn't lua have a json parser? You'd be  better off passing serialized JSON to lua than trying to get a string print of a python dictionary to work.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139363/how-to-parse-json-in-lua) might help

Comment: I can't I am coding in Roblox Lua, they won't allow JSON request to their own server

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, [plenty](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules) (got the link from the bottom of json.org).

Comment: `"key" = value` won't be valid Lua. You need to use `key = value` or `["key"] = value`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hacky, fragile solution since OP says that using a JSON library is out of the question.

It is unclear what values might be stored in the Python dictionary, but it is easily possible that those values could be strings or other dictionaries. The following attempts to handle nested dictionaries, and puts string values in quotes. Note that Lua does not use quotes around keys in table constructors.

```
# Python 3 code
d = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'adict': { 'x': 'a', 'y': 'b'} }

def py_dict_to_lua_table (d):
    lines = '{'
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = py_dict_to_lua_table(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            v = f'"{v}"'
        lines += f'{k} = {v},'
    lines += '}'
    return lines

lua_string = "my_lua_table = " + py_dict_to_lua_table(d)

with open('test.lua', 'w') as f:
    f.write(lua_string)
```

Then, from the command line:

```
$ python3 convert.py
```

Then, from Lua:

```
$ lua -i test.lua 
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> dofile "../lua/lib/utils.lua"
> table.inspect(my_lua_table)
one = 1
adict = 
        y = b
        x = a
two = 2
> my_lua_table.adict.y
b
```

Note that if the Python dictionary contains inconvenient values, e.g. arrays, this will not work. The `py_dict_to_lua_table` function would have to be augmented to represent Python arrays as Lua tables (or what-have-you). Another reason to just use a JSON parsing library, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = []
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    lines.append(f'{"{key}"={value}} ')
with open("./dict.txt", "w"): as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: I don't know how this has managed to collect three upvotes; I count two syntax errors, and even if these are fixed, the code won't work for a couple of other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder):

```
from json import JSONEncoder

encoder = JSONEncoder(separators=[', ', ' = '])
dict_str = encoder.encode({'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3, 'd': [4, 5]}})

print(dict_str)
```

Output:

```
{"a" = 1, "b" = {"c" = 3, "d" = [4, 5]}}
```

Comment: Obviously the square brackets can't be in a Lua table, but the quoted keys have to be fixed, too.